# Multiple level of inheritance confusion

Tags: java, inheritance

I am working on this project where I need to have multiple levels of inheritance for a hierarchic system. The hierarchy works like this, Employee(Abstract) -> Technical Employee(Abstract) --> Software Engineer and Technical Lead.

The thing I am attempting to do is create a sort of "manager variable" in one of those classes to sufficiently establish an "is-a" relationship between the Technical Lead and Software Engineer. Essentially, I need to create a new TechnicalLead that is a Manager. The TechnicalLead's base salary should be 1.3 times that of a 
TechnicalEmployee. TechnicalLeads should have a default headcount of 4.

I couldn't wrap my head around this idea, can someone explain this to me how it's done? I know how inheritance works but when it comes to carefully keep tracking of these, it genuinely seems that I am pretty terrible at it. Technically speaking I don't where to write what.

*Employee*

```
abstract class Employee {

private String name;
protected double baseSalary;

Employee(String name, int baseSalary){
    this.name = name;
    this.baseSalary = baseSalary;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getBaseSalary() {
    return baseSalary;
   }
}
```

*Technical Employee*

```
abstract class TechnicalEmployee extends Employee{

private int checkIns;

TechnicalEmployee(String name){
    super(name, 75000);
  } 
}
```

*Technical Lead*

```
class TechnicalLead extends TechnicalEmployee{

private int headCount;

TechnicalLead(String name) {
    super(name);
    baseSalary = getBaseSalary()*1.3;
    this.headCount = 4;
  }
}
```

Another quick question, in this part of the code; `baseSalary = getBaseSalary()*1.3;` Do I need to define the baseSalary as protected? in order to access the private field.

Comment: The Java and multiple inheritance tags don't go together. Please read the tag instructions/description before slapping them on

Comment: Got it, rookie mistakes.

Comment: What @Mad Physicist is asking you is to please remove the multiple-inheritance tag. Java only uses single-inheritance.

Comment: Sure indeed. I fixed the tag again now, hopefully, someone can explain the actual situation to me.

Comment: Are we talking about a hypothetical problem or do you have a real situation to model?

Comment: This is a completely hypothetical question.

Comment: Java inheritance is not made for general purpose problems and simplifies the world in a way that you can express certain situations with Java mechanics. In most cases, talking about a completely hypothetical situation without a real use case is nice to do but nothing that SO is useful for.

Comment: In general inheritance is only useful for internal programming constructs. It cannot be used in practice for hierarchies such as you describe. Consider for example what happens when an employee acquires a technical qualification, becomes a manager, gets demoted, etc. You can't be changing the employee's object model on the fly. This kind of thing is handled via attributes, not inheritance, in the real world.

Comment: What would you recommend? @user207421

Comment: @swichztra. A good starting point would be to try to code something concrete.  When you run into a specific problem, SO becomes a good forum. It's not very good for this sort of abstract thing.

Answer (score 0):

Alright after sometimes I figured it out. Here is the solution to the problem.

I added a manager variable into Employee class with their corresponding setter and getter for later use;

```
abstract class Employee {

private String name;
protected double baseSalary;
protected Employee manager; // This is what I've added.

Employee(String name, int baseSalary){
    this.name = name;
    this.baseSalary = baseSalary;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getBaseSalary() {
    return baseSalary;
}

public String getManager() {
    return manager.getName();
}

public void setManager(Employee manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
   }
}
```

And then I've added a Technical Lead object to Technical Employee so that we can set the manager in non-abstract classes such as Software Engineer.

```
abstract class TechnicalEmployee extends Employee{

private int checkIns;
private TechnicalLead technicalLead; // This is the manager of the technical employee..

TechnicalEmployee(String name){
    super(name, 75000);
    this.manager = technicalLead;
    }
}
```

For demonstration purposes, I've created a main and test it in the following way;

```
public class CompanyManagement {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SoftwareEngineer s1 = new SoftwareEngineer("Patates");
    TechnicalLead t1 = new TechnicalLead("Patlıcan");
    s1.setManager(t1);
    System.out.println(s1.getManager());

    }
}
```

And the outcome was; Patlıcan. So it seems that it's working. Thanks for everyone.